# WebApi Swagger: API Endpoints empty list

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, owin, swashbuckle

**Problem:** Swagger runs fine in my .NET WebAPI project, but no API endpoint is listed.

[image]

This is what i get from: http://localhost:62536/swagger/docs/v1

```
{
   "swagger":"2.0",
   "info":{
      "version":"v1",
      "title":"Backend.WebApi"
   },
   "host":"localhost:62536",
   "schemes":[
      "http"
   ],
   "paths":{

   },
   "definitions":{

   }
}
```

**swaggerConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using Backend.WebApi;
using Swashbuckle.Application;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace Backend.WebApi
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {


                        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Backend.WebApi");

                    })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>

                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a controller example:

**testController.cs**

```
 namespace Backend.WebApi.Controllers
    {


    [Authorize]
    [RoutePrefix("api/test")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IAppService _appService;

        public TestController(IAppService appService)
        {
            _appService = appService;
        }

        [Route("vehicles/all")]
        public List<VehicleViewModel> GetVehicles()
        {
            return _appService.GetVehicles();
        }
[...]
```

I tried enabling XML comment too (since my app has some of them), but nothing pops up on the list.
Am i missing something?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

- *First attempt*: calling swagger register from WebApiConfig.cs -> **NOT WORKING**

**webConfigApi.cs**

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
        {
            public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
                // Web API configuration and services
                AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

                SwaggerConfig.Register();
                ConfigureIoC(config);


                // Web API routes
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional    }
                );

                var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
                jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            }
```

**swaggerConfig.cs**

```
// [assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace Backend.WebApi
```

Comment: Does order matter here? It's like swashbuckle is generating the schema before the route map exists in the api explorer. Try moving the `SwaggerConfig.Register();` to the bottom of `WebApiConfig.Register()`

Comment: I don't know if order matters actually. I tried as you suggested but i still get the empty list.

Comment: @ATerry yes the order does matter. I had to put this towards the top of my logic, before the .config is assigned to my application. I am using Owin too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moving the config part from `SwaggerConfig.cs` to `WebApiConfig.cs` fixed the issue, probably due to the fact we're using `OWIN` on our project.

**webApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            [...]
            config
            .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Backend.WebApi"))
            .EnableSwaggerUi();
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped me solve my issue. For me, though, I needed to place the .EnableSwagger() before I assign the .config to my application. I had it placed after the .config assignment, so I wasn't get any output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the following line in the WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   ...
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
   ...
}
```

It will register all the route of your web api.

Comment: Nope, i do have that line in the webApiConfig.cs :(

Comment: Comment the following line :

_[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]_

And call the register function into the WebApiConfig.cs

I know that a lot of people have some trouble with this PreApplicationStartMethod attribute.

Comment: by doing that swagger doesn't even start (404).

Comment: ah ok, i'll try.

Comment: Then i'm clueless ... Sorry. 
Your problem is related to the ApiExplorer class [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.apiexplorer%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).
I suggest you to dig information about it.